# How to use variable across contexts in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In below code every call to subscriber_with_99_users creates a new subscriber with 99 users, which I don't want. How can I fix this to only create the subscriber once and return it in all subsequent calls or is there a better way to do this.

```
describe "#as_json" do

context "in 'users' path for a subscriber with 99 users" do

  let(:presenter_options) { { path: 'users', page: 1, per_page: 10 } }

  let(:subscriber_with_99_users) {
    if (@subs_with_99_users)
      @subs_with_99_users
    else
      @subs_with_99_users = get_subscriber_with_many_users 99
    end
  }

  subject { subscriber_presenter.as_json.fetch('users').length } 

  context "and pagination with page size of 10" do 

    {1 => 10, 10 => 9, 11 => 0, 100 => 0}.each do |page, count|
      context "for page #{page}" do
        let(:subscriber_presenter) { 
          Fabricate(:subscriber_presenter, subscriber: subscriber_with_99_users, options: presenter_options.merge(page: page)) 
        }
        it "returns #{count} users" do
          should == count
        end
      end
    end

  end

end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do things across contexts you'll probably want to turn off transactional fixtures. This is easily done

```
ActiveSupport::TestCase.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Although it would probably be better if you could strategically set up your variables in a Before block:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-13/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks!